# I have my store with combine reducers.. My store has many state variables. but i dont want to listen to change in specific variable

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to find a way to subscribe change in specific value in  store
I have tried using subscribe.. but it is triggered on change of every value.. but i want to eleminate some from the store

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selector library, like [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to subscribe only to changes in a part of your store

Comment: ok..let me change my question as... i want to subscribe for all the values in store except fro some